# Spring context indexer causes issues with hibernate entity mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a project that is split between multiple modules, each module is imported into the main one as a maven dependency.
Persistence entities can be located at any of the projects but under the same package.
I have been trying to improve the startup time of the application by using the spring-context-indexer but it seems to cause an issue with detecting entities.
My @EntityScan is configured like this:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.botscrew", "com.botscrew.demoadminpanel.entity.jpa","com.botscrew.admin.entity"})
```

The strange thing is that error looks like this

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.botscrew.admin.entity.Bot.amioWhatsAppConfigs references an unknown entity: com.botscrew.admin.entity.services.configs.AmioWhatsAppConfigs
```

Essentially both entities are located under the same package but Bot entity was resolved but AmioWhatsAppConfigs was not.

The application starts perfectly fine without spring indexer.

I am using spring boot 2.2.1.RELEASE

Entities classes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@ToString(of = {"id", "name"})
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "admin_bot")
@DiscriminatorValue("Bot")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Bot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Convert(converter = EmojiConverter.class)
    private String name;

    private Integer timezone;

    private String greetingText;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "tinyint(1) default 1")
    private Boolean active;

    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private String publicIdentifier;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PersistentMenuEntity persistentMenuEntity;

    //TODO FetchType.LAZY
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "widget_id")
    private Widget widget;

    //TODO FetchType.LAZY
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private MessengerConfigs messengerConfigs;

    //TODO FetchType.LAZY
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private AmioWhatsAppConfigs amioWhatsAppConfigs;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TwilioConfigs twilioConfigs;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private DialogflowConfigs dialogflowConfigs;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ChatbaseConfig chatbaseConfig;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private SupportSettings supportSettings;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bot")
    private List<Broadcast> broadcasts;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "admin_bot_features",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "bot_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "feature_id")})
    private Set<Feature> features;

    public Bot() {
        this.active = true;
    }

    public Bot(String name, DefaultWidgetProperties defaultWidgetProperties) {
        this.publicIdentifier = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.chatbaseConfig = new ChatbaseConfig();
        this.amioWhatsAppConfigs = new AmioWhatsAppConfigs();
        this.timezone = 0;
        this.name = name;
        this.active = true;
        this.messengerConfigs = new MessengerConfigs();
        this.dialogflowConfigs = new DialogflowConfigs();
        this.widget = new Widget(defaultWidgetProperties);
        this.supportSettings = new SupportSettings(false);
    }
    
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Accessors(chain = true)
@ToString
@Table(name = "admin_amio_whatsapp_configs")
public class AmioWhatsAppConfigs implements AmioWhatsAppBot {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String channelId;
    private String accessToken;
    private String secret;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my answer please  check example

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.botscrew", 
"com.botscrew.demoadminpanel.entity.jpa","com.botscrew.admin.entity.services.configs.*"})
```

Comment: yep, all Entities are from javax.persistence

Comment: Okey Please wait

Comment: Please add your entity class

Comment: I tried a lot of different combinations, I also don't think the issue is with the entity scan, otherwise, I would be getting this error for many other entities as well.